# Chosen jquery script is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

I'm using jQuery chosen in select element to make it more user friendly, but it's not working when i'm doing copy chosen div to another div using jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chosen").chosen({});

  $("#movechosen").click(function() {
    var chosenHtml = $(".mycontainer").html();
    $(".movecontainer").append(chosenHtml);
  });
});
```

```html
   <div class="mycontainer" style="background:#ddd">
     Container 1: <select class="chosen" multiple>
       <option>Select option</option>
       <option>USA</option>
       <option>Germany</option>
       <option>India</option>
       <option>China</option>
       <option>Canada</option>
       <option>Australia</option>
     </select>
   </div>
  <div class="movecontainer" style="background:#e1e1e1">
     Container 2 : 
  </div>
<input type="button" value="copy to container 2" id="movechosen" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.1/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.1/chosen.css" />
```

It's getting copy to another container but when you focus on chosen it will not load elements available in it.

Comment: whats with the empty object?

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand you.

Comment: the empty object in the initialization of the plugin

Comment: Second container will be empty at page load time i want to copy the chosen select from container one to another, it's getting copy but if you mark, chosen dropdown stop working when do copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destroy the plugin when you clone the elements and then reinitialize them after the append:

try the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chosen").chosen();

  $("#movechosen").click(function() {
     $(".chosen").chosen("destroy");
    var chosenHtml = $(".mycontainer").html();
    $(".movecontainer").append(chosenHtml);
    $(".chosen").chosen();

  });
});
```

```html
<div class="mycontainer" style="background:#ddd">
     Container 1: <select class="chosen" multiple>
       <option>Select option</option>
       <option>USA</option>
       <option>Germany</option>
       <option>India</option>
       <option>China</option>
       <option>Canada</option>
       <option>Australia</option>
     </select>
   </div>
  <div class="movecontainer" style="background:#e1e1e1">
     Container 2 : 
  </div>
<input type="button" value="copy to container 2" id="movechosen" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.1/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.1/chosen.css" />
```

Comment: Thank you, i was facing this issue from long back, i appreciate your help.